# Getting the label of a BarChart's bar on click dc.js

Tags: javascript, html, click, bar-chart, dc.js

So I am trying to make a ordinal bar chart that when you click on a bar it accesses the label of the bar chart, essentially the xUnit value but it is ordinal. I have tried using this method:

```
barChart.on('renderlet.barclicker', function(chart, filter)
{
    chart.selectAll('rect.bar').on('click.custom', function(d) {
        console.log("CLICKED!!");
    });
});
```

but I am unsure on how to access the label of the bar and the click event does not even call. (CLICKED!! was never returned in the console).I got the chart to be clickable as a whole using

```
barChart.on('click' , function(chart){

});
```

however I am unable to replicate my success with only bars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going wrong with capturing the click event. I copied and pasted your code into the dc.js examples bar.html and ordinal-bar.html, and I am seeing console logs when I click on bars.

As for accessing the label, probably the best way is to use the same `.label()` accessor function that the chart itself uses:

```
          console.log(chart.label()(d));
```